# Markdown Render Newlines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, format, ruby-on-rails-5, markdown

I'm working on a Project and give an user the possibility to create a Post. 
With loading the Post, i'm calling the **markdown** method, to extract links and format the text.

Now i got a Problem. 
By writing *"1. Example"* the Output in the Post is a list. 
By just writing "1.Example"_ without the whitespace between the point and the text, it'working fine. 
My markdown method:

```
@preview = nil
options = {
  autolink: true,
  hard_wrap: true
}
begin
  URI.extract(text, ['http', 'https', 'www']).each do |uri|
    unless text.include?("<a")
      text = text.gsub( uri, "<a href=\"#{uri}\" target=\"_blank\">#{uri}</a>" )
      @preview = LinkThumbnailer.generate(uri)
    end
  end
rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError => e
end


renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer)

markdown.render(text).html_safe
```

May you know, how to fix it.. I don't want the list, i just want the Output to be the same like the Input!

Thank you, for your time!

**EDIT** Added a photo to show the output.[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please show the html output of both of these inputs?

Comment: What do newlines (mentioned in your title) have to do with lists (mentioned in your question)? Are you aware that Markdown includes support for lists, and are there other valid Markdown syntaxes that you wish to ignore?

Comment: Added the Photo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a [backslash escape](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) in your Markdown source. As the rules explain:

> Markdown allows you to use backslash escapes to generate literal characters which would otherwise have special meaning in Markdown’s formatting syntax.

Among the characters which backlash escaping supports is the dot (`.`). Therefore your source text should look like this:

```
1\. Example
```

Which results in this HTML:

```
<p>1. Example</p>
```

And renders as:

> 1. Example

Answer (score 0):

By default you're going to get the list. Markdown is after all looking for syntax that it recognises in order to generate mark up.

In order to skip particular markdown features I think you're going to need to provide your own [custom renderer](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#and-you-can-even-cook-your-own).

If you define a new renderer:

```
class NoListRenderer < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def list(contents, list_type)
    contents
  end

  def list_item(text, list_type)
    text
  end
end
```

and use an instance of that instead of the default renderer class when you create your `markdown` instance it should skip the default list processing. (NB. I haven't tested this code):

```
renderer = NoListRenderer.new(options)
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer)
```